Google Sheets Filtering - Filter by Condition
Quite a complex one that I'm struggling to figure out.
I am a member of a sports club aiming to produce a changing list of players who are umpires to select from.
We have 5 of 9 teams playing at home each week and each team has umpires in them. We have to provide 2 umpires per match.
I have a list of names and their designated teams, (List A) e.g.
Player 1 - Team 1
Player 2 - Team 1
Player 3 - Team 2
Player 4 - Team 3
etc.
I have a list of which teams are at home each week, List B) e.g.
Week 1 - Team 1 & 3
Week 2 - Team 2 and 3
etc.
I would like to filter List A by List B as a "Filter by Condition" formula in Google Sheets so that if I change the Week in a cell, the List A filter will automatically change to have a singular list of umpires also playing at home each week. e.g.
Week 1 will filter List A to only show player 1, 2 and 4
Week 2 will filter List A to only show player 3 and 4
Previously set up is a combined list of all players in column 1, column 2 has their team number (not used in this initial set up), then a filter set up to search another sheet for the player name and if they player has set "Available" for that date. Used the below formula
=filter('AVAILABILITY FORM RESPONSES'!C:C,'AVAILABILITY FORM RESPONSES'!$B:$B=$A6)
This outputs a list of names that have set themselves as Available for the specified date. I then use data validation to update the drop-down list to only show those set as "Available"
Originally set up as filter by responded individuals
e.g. umpires said they were available so if the date matched being available it produce a list of every umpire whom said they were available into a drop down list.
I want to change the approach and not collect manual Availability anymore and have the drop down populated by a list which lists all players at home that week based on their team designation.
List A - Team
List B - Date with Team List
List C - Contains all players from teams in List B by date
Intended Output - Drop down list containing list names of all players of teams at Home on that date



Team 1
Team 2
Team 3
Team 4




P1
P3
P5
P6


P2
P4

P7





P8






Date 1
Date 2
Date 3




Team 1
Team 1
Team 2


Team 2
Team 3
Team 4






Date
Venue
Umpire 1
Umpire 2




Date 1
Home
"Drop Down List of every Player from Team 1 & 2"
"Drop Down List of every Player from Team 1 & 2"


Date 2
Home
"Drop Down List of every Player from Team 1 & 3"
"Drop Down List of every Player from Team 1 & 3"



Date 1 Drop Down to contain players: P1, P2, P3, P4
Date 2 Drop Down to contain players: P1, P2, P5
Below is the table I want to be automatically created based on List A and List B
It would be a multi condition filter along the lines of "IF Date = Date 1, List Players from Team IN Column A"



Date 1
Date 2
Date 3




P1
P1
P3


P2
P2
P4


P3
P5
P6


P4

P7




P8



Question. I need assistance with the formulae I need to use to combine the lists of players into a single list based on a date. If I have that formula, I can solve the rest with what I already have.

Okay, here's something you can try. I added the table below so you can understand how the cell references work. That way you can modify it how you need.Credit to @rockinfreakshow for teaching me how they create a null variable for use with reduce-vstack.



A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H




Team 1
Team 2
Team 3
Team 4

Date 1
Date 2
Date 3


P1
P3
P5
P6

Team 1
Team 1
Team 2


P2
P4

P7

Team 2
Team 3
Team 4





P8







   =LET(
   z,tocol(,1),
   dates,{F:H},
   teams,{A2:D},
   names,{A1:D1},
      bycol(dates,lambda(k,hstack(
         reduce(z,k,LAMBDA(a,c,vstack(a,tocol(iferror(CHOOSECOLS(teams,MATCH(c,names)),c),1))))))))


Thank you for this. I've adapted it and changed the cell references however I've run into a new issue with it.
Below is my adapted one but it is only bringing through columns L & M and duplicating Column L for the amount of teams in the list
=LET(
z,tocol(,1),
dates,{AVAILABILITY!E:AB},
teams,{Umpires!D2:M},
names,{Umpires!D1:M1},
bycol(dates,lambda(k,hstack( reduce(z,k,LAMBDA(a,c,vstack(a,tocol(iferror(CHOOSECOLS(teams,MATCH(c,names)),c),1))))))))

My Teams are M1-M5, L1-L4 and Umpire
I changed all my team names to Team 1 - 10 and it worked, but I need it to be M1-5, L1-4 and UMPIRE
